# Feature selection with sklearn - ValueError: X has a different shape than during fitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

:) 
Very sorry in advance if my code looks like something a total newbie would write. Down below is a portion of my code in python. I am fiddling with `sklearn` and machine learning techniques.
I trained several Naive Bayes Model based on different datasets and stored them in `trained_models`
Prior this step i created an object `chi_squared` of the SelectPercentile class using the `chi2` function for feature selection.
 From my understanding, i should write  `data_feature_reduced = chi_squared.transform(some_data)` then use `data_feature_reduced` at the time of training like this, ie:  `nb.fit(data_feature_reduced, data.target)`  
This is what did, and stored the results objects  `nb`  ( and some other informations in the list trained_models.

I am now attempting to apply these models on a different set of data ( actually from the same source, if that matters to the question )

```
for name, model, intra_result, dev, training_data, chi_squarer in trained_models:
    cross_results = []
    new_vect= StemmedVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 4), stop_words='english', max_df=0.90, min_df=2)
    for data in demframes:
        data_name = data[0]
        X_test_data = new_vect.fit_transform(data[1].values.astype('U'))
        Y_test_data = data[2]
        chi_squared_test_data = chi_squarer.transform(X_test_data)
        final_results.append((name, "applied to", data[0], model.score(X_test_data,Y_test_data)))
```

I have to admit that I am a bit of stranger to the feature selection part.
Here is the error that i get :

```
ValueError: X has a different shape than during fitting.
```

at line `chi_squared_test_data = chi_squarer.transform(X_test_data)`

I am assuming I am doing feature selection in an incorrect manner, Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: This error is due to this line `new_vect.fit_transform()`. Like your trained models, you should use the same `StemmedVectorizer` which was used at training time

Comment: I think this is what I did. Or should I use the same object ? What difference would it make ?

Comment: The same difference that an already trained model and an untrained model have. The same StemmedVectorizer object will transform the `X_test_data` to same shape, what it had during the training. Currently, you are using different object and fitting on it (fit_transform is fit and transform), hence the shape is different. Hence the error

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone for their help!

I will just paste the comment that helped me solve my problem from @Vivek-Kumar.

> This error is due to this line `new_vect.fit_transform()`. Like your
>   trained models, you should use the same `StemmedVectorizer` which was
>   used at training time.
>
> The same `StemmedVectorize` object will transform the `X_test_data` to same shape, what it had during the training. Currently, you are using different object and fitting on it (`fit_transform` is fit and transform), hence the shape is different. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a pipeline to make it simple? that way you dont have to transform twice and take care of the shapes.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

chi_squarer = SelectKBest(chi2, k=100) # change accordingly
lr = LogisticRegression() # or naive bayes

clf = pipeline.Pipeline([('chi_sq', chi_squarer), ('model', lr)])

# for training:
clf.fit(training_data, targets)

# for predictions:
clf.predict(test_data)
```

you can also add the `new_vect` in the pipeline

Comment: yes. data -> use ur vectorizer -> use the pipeline. change models and value of k according to your needs. read more about pipeline here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html

Comment: I want to use the already trained models for prediction, wont calling the fit method in the pipeline re-train the models ? I am trying to check the accuracy on new data